# Remove duplicate dataframe column items just at the beginning while keeping the last entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

The dataframe below is what I'm trying to plot, but there are several duplicate entries in each column. By maintaining only the final entry, I wish to eliminate the initial repeated components in each column so that they do not appear in the graph(Ignore if duplicates in middle and last).

Could someone please help me solve this issue?

Code I tried, this removes if duplicates in entire row:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns[1:], keep='last')
df = df.groupby((df.shift() != df).cumsum()).filter(lambda x: len(x) < 5)
```

Input:

```
Date    Build1  Build2  Build3  Build4  Build5  Build6
2022-11-26 00:00:00 30  30  30  30  30  30
2022-11-27 00:00:00 30  30  30  30  30  30
2022-11-28 00:00:00 30  30  30  30  30  30
2022-11-29 00:00:00 30  30  30  30  30  30
2022-11-30 00:00:00 30  30  30  30  30  30
2022-12-01 00:00:00 28  30  30  30  30  30
2022-12-02 00:00:00 25  30  30  30  30  30
2022-12-03 00:00:00 25  30  30  30  30  30
2022-12-04 00:00:00 22  28  30  30  30  30
2022-12-05 00:00:00 22  26  30  30  30  30
2022-12-06 00:00:00 22  23  30  30  30  30
2022-12-07 00:00:00 22  22  30  30  30  30
2022-12-08 00:00:00 22  20  30  30  30  30
2022-12-09 00:00:00 22  20  25  30  30  30
2022-12-10 00:00:00 22  20  23  30  30  30
2022-12-11 00:00:00 22  20  23  30  30  30
2022-12-12 00:00:00 22  20  18  30  30  30
2022-12-13 00:00:00 22  20  14  30  30  30
2022-12-14 00:00:00 22  20  11  30  30  30
2022-12-15 00:00:00 22  20  10  27  30  30
2022-12-16 00:00:00 22  20  10  20  30  30
2022-12-17 00:00:00 22  20  10  20  30  30
2022-12-18 00:00:00 22  20  10  20  30  30
2022-12-19 00:00:00 22  20  10  13  30  30
2022-12-20 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   30  30
2022-12-21 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   19  30
2022-12-22 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   11  30
2022-12-23 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   4   30
2022-12-24 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   0   30
2022-12-25 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   0   22
2022-12-26 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   0   15
2022-12-27 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   0   15
2022-12-28 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   0   9
```

Expected output:

```
Date    Build1  Build2  Build3  Build4  Build5  Build6
2022-11-26 00:00:00                     
2022-11-27 00:00:00                     
2022-11-28 00:00:00                     
2022-11-29 00:00:00                     
2022-11-30 00:00:00 30                  
2022-12-01 00:00:00 28                  
2022-12-02 00:00:00 25                  
2022-12-03 00:00:00 25  30              
2022-12-04 00:00:00 22  28              
2022-12-05 00:00:00 22  26              
2022-12-06 00:00:00 22  23              
2022-12-07 00:00:00 22  22              
2022-12-08 00:00:00 22  20  30          
2022-12-09 00:00:00 22  20  25          
2022-12-10 00:00:00 22  20  23          
2022-12-11 00:00:00 22  20  23          
2022-12-12 00:00:00 22  20  18          
2022-12-13 00:00:00 22  20  14          
2022-12-14 00:00:00 22  20  11  30      
2022-12-15 00:00:00 22  20  10  27      
2022-12-16 00:00:00 22  20  10  20      
2022-12-17 00:00:00 22  20  10  20      
2022-12-18 00:00:00 22  20  10  20      
2022-12-19 00:00:00 22  20  10  13      
2022-12-20 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   30  
2022-12-21 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   19  
2022-12-22 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   11  
2022-12-23 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   4   
2022-12-24 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   0   30
2022-12-25 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   0   22
2022-12-26 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   0   15
2022-12-27 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   0   15
2022-12-28 00:00:00 22  20  10  2   0   9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
is_duplicate = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1)
df.where(~is_duplicate, np.nan)
```

which gives

```
                     Date  Build1  Build2  Build3  Build4
0   2022-11-26 00:00:00 30      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   2022-11-27 00:00:00 30      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   2022-11-28 00:00:00 30      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   2022-11-29 00:00:00 30      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   2022-11-30 00:00:00 30      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
5   2022-12-01 00:00:00 28      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
6   2022-12-02 00:00:00 25      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
7   2022-12-03 00:00:00 25      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
8   2022-12-04 00:00:00 22      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
9   2022-12-05 00:00:00 22      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
10  2022-12-06 00:00:00 22      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
11  2022-12-07 00:00:00 22      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
12  2022-12-08 00:00:00 22      30     NaN     NaN     NaN
13  2022-12-09 00:00:00 22      25    30.0     NaN     NaN
14  2022-12-10 00:00:00 22      23    30.0     NaN     NaN
15  2022-12-11 00:00:00 22      23    30.0     NaN     NaN
16  2022-12-12 00:00:00 22      18    30.0     NaN     NaN
17  2022-12-13 00:00:00 22      14    30.0     NaN     NaN
18  2022-12-14 00:00:00 22      11    30.0     NaN     NaN
19  2022-12-15 00:00:00 22      10    27.0    30.0     NaN
20  2022-12-16 00:00:00 22      10    20.0    30.0     NaN
21  2022-12-17 00:00:00 22      10    20.0    30.0     NaN
22  2022-12-18 00:00:00 22      10    20.0    30.0     NaN
23  2022-12-19 00:00:00 22      10    13.0    30.0     NaN
24  2022-12-20 00:00:00 22      10     2.0    30.0     NaN
25  2022-12-21 00:00:00 22      10     2.0    19.0    30.0
26  2022-12-22 00:00:00 22      10     2.0    11.0    30.0
27  2022-12-23 00:00:00 22      10     2.0     4.0    30.0
28  2022-12-24 00:00:00 22      10     2.0     0.0    30.0
29  2022-12-25 00:00:00 22      10     2.0     0.0    22.0
30  2022-12-26 00:00:00 22      10     2.0     0.0    15.0
31  2022-12-27 00:00:00 22      10     2.0     0.0    15.0
32  2022-12-28 00:00:00 22      10     2.0     0.0     9.0
```

or

```
is_duplicate = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1)
print(df.where(~is_duplicate, ''))
```

which gives:

```
                     Date  Build1 Build2 Build3 Build4
0   2022-11-26 00:00:00 30      30                     
1   2022-11-27 00:00:00 30      30                     
2   2022-11-28 00:00:00 30      30                     
3   2022-11-29 00:00:00 30      30                     
4   2022-11-30 00:00:00 30      30                     
5   2022-12-01 00:00:00 28      30                     
6   2022-12-02 00:00:00 25      30                     
7   2022-12-03 00:00:00 25      30                     
8   2022-12-04 00:00:00 22      30                     
9   2022-12-05 00:00:00 22      30                     
10  2022-12-06 00:00:00 22      30                     
11  2022-12-07 00:00:00 22      30                     
12  2022-12-08 00:00:00 22      30                     
13  2022-12-09 00:00:00 22      25     30              
14  2022-12-10 00:00:00 22      23     30              
15  2022-12-11 00:00:00 22      23     30              
16  2022-12-12 00:00:00 22      18     30              
17  2022-12-13 00:00:00 22      14     30              
18  2022-12-14 00:00:00 22      11     30              
19  2022-12-15 00:00:00 22      10     27     30       
20  2022-12-16 00:00:00 22      10     20     30       
21  2022-12-17 00:00:00 22      10     20     30       
22  2022-12-18 00:00:00 22      10     20     30       
23  2022-12-19 00:00:00 22      10     13     30       
24  2022-12-20 00:00:00 22      10      2     30       
25  2022-12-21 00:00:00 22      10      2     19     30
26  2022-12-22 00:00:00 22      10      2     11     30
27  2022-12-23 00:00:00 22      10      2      4     30
28  2022-12-24 00:00:00 22      10      2      0     30
29  2022-12-25 00:00:00 22      10      2      0     22
30  2022-12-26 00:00:00 22      10      2      0     15
31  2022-12-27 00:00:00 22      10      2      0     15
32  2022-12-28 00:00:00 22      10      2      0      9
```